# Does it exist a Jpa/Hibernate annotation to mark the field as generated default by database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assuming we have a value that is generated as default in database

```
uuid UUID    DEFAULT     uuid_generate_v4()
```

How do I mark the field for the subsequent select that retrieves the value?

I would like to avoid to explicitely call `entityManager.refresh()`,
I marked the column with the Hibernate annotation
`@Generated(event = { INSERT, UPDATE })`
But this makes the field not writeable. In this case might be ok, but there might be fields which I want to be generated on insert as defaults and then be able to update them, this annotation seems to limit this.

Are there other annotation I don't know? Or what is the usual approach using JPA/Hibernate with default fields?
Also, JPA annotation would be preferrable.

It seems to me a common scenario but I can't find much about it.

I tried different combinations, but they are not as flexible as I think they should be. I also implemented my own annotation in the same way that `@Generated` works, but I don't want to use a custom annotation since I might not be aware of side effects

Comment: Did you already see this? https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-on-db-generated/

Comment: @queeg that refers to IDs, not to a generic field

Comment: Would it then be sufficient to implement a readonly property with a getter but no setter method?

Comment: @queeg The problem is how to decide which fields are retrieved after an insert or an update

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

- You know some properties are db-generated and thus you mark them 'dirty' after the insert operation, hoping the persistence layer would perform a read operation before returning the real objects.
- Another possibility would be to perform a read immediately after insert, making you ready for any property retrieval that might come next.